# Получение ключа доступа приложения в VK

Tags: php, api, вконтакте

Всем привет, нужна помощь, хотел сделать бота в группу в вк, но появилась ошибка при получении токена приложения. Перехожу по такой ссылке:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=*******&display=page&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=friends,photos,audio,video,status,messages,wall,groups,offline,stats,email&response_type=token&v=5.63
```

(Вместо звёздочек стоит ID приложения), теперь когда я перехожу по этой ссылке, у меня выходит такая ошибка:

```
error:  "invalid_request"
error_description:  "application was deleted"
```

Может если кто сталкивался и знает как решить проблему, сможет помочь...

Comment: `application was deleted` собсна что не понятно?

Comment: а приложение не удалёно!

Comment: Возможно, вы вводите id от другого приложения? И то, которое вводите - удалено, а то которое смотрите - нет.